# How to resolve nested promises with Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to write something like this but not able to resolve inner promises.

```js
  const traceSamplesRequests = transactionTypes.map(async (transactionType) => {
    // This part should be synchronous since we need transactionNames
    const transactionNames = await api.getTransactionNames();
    return transactionNames.map((transactionName) => api.getTraceSamples());
  });
```

And I want to write with lambda functions with Promise.all not imperative loops.

Comment: `return Promise.all(transactionNames.map(...))`. You'll also want `Promise.all()` around the `transactionTypes.map(...)` too

Comment: @Phil is correct. There's no built-in support. You can always write a recursive helper if you find yourself repeating it

Comment: @Phil sorry I have seen your answer after I posted mine :D

Answer (score 3):

So, `.map()` is not promise-aware.  It calls the callback and just dutifully collects the return value from the callback and advances to the next iteration of the loop.  Since your callback is `async` with an `await` in it, that return value is an unresolved promise.  So, what you get back from `.map()` is an array of promises.

So, there is no way to use `.map()` or any of the array iteration methods without then using something to wait for the promises.

It sounds like you already know this, but with the code you have, you would insert two `Promise.all()` statements:

```
  const traceSamplesRequests = await Promise.all(transactionTypes.map(async (transactionType) => {
    // This part should be synchronous since we need transactionNames
    const transactionNames = await api.getTransactionNames();
    return Promise.all(transactionNames.map((transactionName) => api.getTraceSamples()));
  }));
```

That would get you an array of values (and the parent function would have to be `async`). This will run all the asynchronous operation in the loop in parallel (all in flight at the same time).

Your other choices are to use a `for` or `while` loop which will suspend loop iteration for each `await` and will run your asynchronous operations in sequence (second iteration of the loop not running until the first is done).

Or, you can write some sort of helper function that would be a promise-aware version of `.map()`.  You'd probably just either use `for` or `.map()` with `Promise.all()` inside the helper function though.

The [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map) promise library has multiple such helper functions as choices to use.  They are designed to work with either promises or plain callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, don't know why -1'd someone

Answer (score 0):

I actually made it work like this:

```js
  const traceSamplesRequests = await Promise.all(
    transactionTypes.map(async (transactionType) => {
      const transactionNames = await api.getTransactionNames({ transactionType });
      return await Promise.all(transactionNames.map((transactionName) => api.getTraceSamples({ transactionType })));
    })
  );
```